# event Func<bool> with 2 handlers: which return to expect?

Tags: c#, events, syntax, event-handling, func

Let's suppose that I have the classes `A` and `B`.

In the class `A`, I have the following event:

```
public event Func<bool> MyEvent;
```

and the following method:

```
public bool GetResult()
{
    return MyEvent();
}
```

And in the class `B`, I have the following constructor:

```
public B()
{
    A a = new A();
    a.MyEvent += a_MyEvent_one;
    a.MyEvent += a_MyEvent_two;

    bool result = a.GetResult();
}

private bool a_MyEvent_one()
{
    return true;
}

private bool a_MyEvent_two()
{
    return false;
}
```

So, what to expect as result in the end of the constructor of class `B`, and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get the result of whichever handle was added most recently.

Having said that, you should not rely on this behavior.  This is why events conceptually shouldn't use delegates with a return value.  Even though the behavior is defined, most programmers won't be aware of what this does, and so the code will be confusing.  A programmer could also change the order that handlers are defined if they have the expectation that the order is not important (which is, generally, a reasonable assumption).

Note that this is only the case for events that do not define their own `add` and `remove` methods.  The automatic implementation will combine new handlers into a MultiCastDelegate, which maintains this property.  An event that uses custom `add`/`remove` methods can do whatever it wants, and it can fire the event however it wants, allowing it to potentially do any number of things, such as choosing a different return value to use, use all return values, etc.  Because of this if see an event in a class that you cannot view the source code of, you cannot know whether or not this property will be maintained.  You cannot know if it defines custom `add`/`remove` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a multicast delegate will always return the return value of the last method in the delegate.
In your case, that would be `false`.